# Миксины(примеси) в es6?

Tags: javascript

Изучил миксины в es5 (т.е. через самописную функцию)

```
var extend = function(target) { // get target [0] and mixins
    if(!arguments[1]) { // if no mixins in arguments[]
        return; // quit
    }

    for(i=1; i < arguments.length; i++) { // skip [0] as its the target
        var source = arguments[i]; // get current mxin

        console.log(source);

        for(var prop in source) { // inner loop with current mixin
            if(!target[prop] && source.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { // antiduplicate
                target[prop] = source[prop]; // assign each
            }
        }
    }
};
```

теперь изучаю es6 и правильно я понимаю что в нем уже не используются самописные функции для миксинов, и есть внутренняя функция для примесей?

Comment: там нет миксинов, декораторы то еще в подвешенном состоянии

Answer (score -3, accepted):

В самом языке миксинов нет, но вместо

```js
var extend = function(target) { // get target [0] and mixins
    if(!arguments[1]) { // if no mixins in arguments[]
        return; // quit
    }

    for(i=1; i < arguments.length; i++) { // skip [0] as its the target
        var source = arguments[i]; // get current mxin

        // console.log(source);

        for(var prop in source) { // inner loop with current mixin
            if(!target[prop] && source.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { // antiduplicate
                target[prop] = source[prop]; // assign each
            }
        }
    }
};

var obj = {
  a: 5
}

extend(obj, { b: 6})

console.log(obj)
```

Можно написать:

```js
function extend (obj) {
  Object.assign(obj, ...arguments)

}

let obj = {
  a: 5
}

extend(obj, { b: 6}, { c: 7, d: { a: 8 } })

console.log(obj)
```

Но как тут так и у Вас идет мутирование оригинального объекта, плохая практика, нужно возвращать новый объект.

```js
const oldObj = {
  a: 5
}

const newObj = extend(oldObj, { b: 6}, { c: 7, d: { a: 8 } })

console.log(oldObj, newObj)

function extend (obj) {
  // делает глубокую копию чтобы убрать ссылки на объекты
  return copy(Object.assign({}, obj, ...arguments))
}

function copy (obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
}
```

В коде приставлен самый простой и быстрый вариант клонирования, но не совсем полноценно работает, подробней можете прочитать [ЗДЕСЬ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).

Я обычно использую [этот npm пакет](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep) для этого.

Comment: Но как тут так и у Вас идет мутирование оригинального объекта, плохая практика, нужно возвращать новый объект. - Т.е. лучше эту мою самописную функцию Миксина не использовать?

Comment: Да, щас может напишу что лучше использовать

Comment: Еще вопрос https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Mix-ins тут вот дается пример миксинов к es6 классам. Но что-то непонятно. Этот код с примера их делает тоже самое что и мой? т.е. добавляет свои методы без наследования.

Comment: там по сути цепочка наследования, которая вынесена в функции. Ваш код работает не с классами, а объектами

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` упадет если есть циклические ссылки + методы так не 
копируются

Comment: да, свой код я понимаю. А их код  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Mix-ins что делает с классами так и не понял когда смотрел этот пункт mix-in ) думал это тоже примесь для объектов

Comment: @TheOs мы возвращаем новый класс, который наследуется от переданного. Это новая фича, все эти классы и слово `extends`

Comment: @ThisMan это да, я хотел дать эту ссылку, тут видно как лучше клонировать. Путь товарищ выбирает по своей ситуации, я дал самый простой вариант. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: @ ThisMan  так это просто subClass выходит? то же самое что 
class Child extends Parent?

Comment: тот код то же самое что и `class Foo {
  calc() { }
  randomize() { }
}
class Bar extends Foo { }`

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, не тот же.

Comment: Вы непоследовательны. Почему вы делаете глубокую копию первого аргумента, но поверхностную всех остальных? Надо или заморочиться глубоким клонированием всех-всех-всех объектов, или использовать классическое `Object.assign({}, obj, ...arguments)`

Comment: Забыл) Спасибо, переделал.

Comment: В общем я в итоге ничего не понял до конца. По-моему я про примеси писал, а вы дали ответ про клонирование объекта. Но выбираю ваш ответ правильным, потому что тут все настолько запутались уже, что не важно.